# Excel VBA: Import data from all text files in a directory onto a new row in excel?

Tags: vba, excel, text-files

I am using VBA to import all the data from a single text file onto a new row in excel and then once the data from the text file is imported move the text file to another location/directory. I have done this much.

However now I have multiple text files in a directory and want to get the data from each text file and insert it onto a new row so I end up getting the following results:

```
Text File 1
A
B
C
D


Text File 2
T
L
V
P


Excel:
Column A     Column B       Column C         Column D        
A            B              C                D   
T            L              V                P
```

Here is my code:

```
Sub ImportFile()

    Dim rowCount As Long

    rowCount = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1

    If Cells(1, 1).Value = "" Then rowCount = 1


    Close #1
    Open "Z:\Incident Logs\Unactioned\IN94LQ3Z.txt" For Input As #1
    A = 1
     Do While Not EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, TextLine
            Cells(rowCount, A) = TextLine
            A = A + 1
        Loop
    Close #1


 Dim d As String, ext, x
Dim srcPath As String, destPath As String, srcFile As String
srcPath = "Z:\Incident Logs\Unactioned\"
destPath = "Z:\Incident Logs\Actioned\"
ext = Array("*.txt", "*.xls")
For Each x In ext
    d = Dir(srcPath & x)
        Do While d <> ""
            srcFile = srcPath & d
            FileCopy srcFile, destPath & d
            Kill srcFile
            d = Dir
        Loop
Next


End Sub
```

Please can someone show me a way of doing what i need? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You will need to incorporate the following snippet with your code, where you replace the hard coded file path and file name. Also you will need to make sure that you have your index right as you open new files.

```
Sub AllFilesInFolder()
    Dim myFolder As String, myFile As String
    myFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            myFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With
    myFile = Dir(myFolder & "\*.txt") '
    Do While myFile <> ""
        Open myFolder & "\" & myFile For Input As #1
        .....

        myFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not understand your answer, is it possible for you to show me how your code would work with mine? thanks